# Link images in QGIS map for qgis2web Leaflet export published on GitHub?

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web, github, directory

When I open the index.html file (from the qgis2web export) with my browser (locally) all my images are properly displayed.

[image]

However, after uploading my web map files to github and publishing it with GitHub pages, none of the images are displayed.

[image]

I think this could be related to my file directory's structure because when I export my web map from qgis, the "images" folder is empty.

I tried to add the images inside subsequently but this doesn't change anything.

you can check my repo here https://github.com/elieilex/Patches-map
and the map here https://elieilex.github.io/Patches-map/#18/51.44431/5.45806

Comment: I suggest reviewing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works for you locally, but for your map that is published on GitHub your popup construction function `pop_Actions_13(feature, layer)` constructs wrong image addresses.

These are the changes needed when image address is constructed from feature property:

- replacing `/` with `_` has to be removed;
- first three characters `../` of property has to be skiped;
- property value `no` has to be treated the same as `NULL` value.

So popup construction function has to look something like this:

```
function pop_Actions_13(feature, layer) {
  var popupContent = '<table>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">OCCURENCE</th>\
        <td>' + (feature.properties['ACTION NUMBER'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['ACTION NUMBER'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">ACTION</th>\
        <td>' + (feature.properties['ACTION'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['ACTION'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">PHOTO</th>\
        <td>' + (((feature.properties['PHOTO'] !== null) && (feature.properties['PHOTO'] !== 'no'))  ? '<img src="images/' + String(feature.properties['PHOTO']).trim().substring(3) + '" '+ 'class=popupImage' +'>' : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">DESCRIPTION</th>\
        <td>' + (feature.properties['DESCRIPTION'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['DESCRIPTION'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">UPDATE</th>\
        <td>' + (feature.properties['UPDATE'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['UPDATE'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr>\
        <th scope="row">photo</th>\
        <td>' + (feature.properties['updated photo'] !== null ? '<img src="images/' + String(feature.properties['updated photo']).trim().substring(3) + '" '+ 'class=popupImage' +'>' : '') + '</td>\
      </tr>\
    </table>';
  layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I suspected that the replacement of / with _ has to and the first three characters ../ of property were an issue but I honestly had no clue how to address it. Thank you for the code :)